How do you determine if an Hamiltonian allows entanglement and when?
Sorry for the vague setup, but I'm a noob and I'm trying to understand, so please be patient. Let's say that I have a tight-binding, 2D, square lattice Hamiltonian
$$
H = H_t + H_{interaction} + H_{\mu}
$$
and I want to know when and where entanglement can or cannot be present in the phase diagram. Is it even a property of the Hamiltonian? Does it depend on how the atoms/electron have been put together to create the lattice?
If not, is there a way to measure it starting from the Hamiltonian? From the Green's function? From the eigenstates? In other words what is the order parameter for entanglement?
Thank you very much in advance, please don't be upset

What do you mean by there being entanglement in the phase diagram? You mean regions where the ground state shows entanglement?

Yes! That's exactly what I mean

I think that this is a really hard problem, mostly because $H_{interaction}$ cannot be considered as a small perturbation for a tight-binding model. Otherwise, it is easy to see that the effect, using first order perturbation theory in second quantization, is to have generic entangled states. Some conditions could possibly be seen then.

An interaction will generally result in entanglement! However, it may be negligibly small. The entanglement of ground states is certainly a property of a Hamiltonian in that $H$ determines the phase structure, and quantum phases are characterizable in terms of their patterns of entanglement. But Idk if anything can be said withotu details of these terms! Trivial quantum states may be unentangled (e.g., a paramagnet). Nontrivial quantum states have area-law entanglement. Critical quantum states have log$L$ entanglement. You can't necessarily work this out from observables / Green's functions.
